# Nested if .. else

Tags: conditionals

What's wrong with the syntax of the `\if...\else \if...\else...\fi` below?

My intention is that if either `OptA` is true, then `\which` is defined to be `Chose A`, or if instead `OptB` is true, then `\which` is defined to be `Chose B`, or else if neither is true, then `\which` is defined to be `Chose other`.

But despite setting `OptA` to have value `true`, I still find that `\which` produces `Chose other`.

```
  \documentclass{article}
  
  \usepackage{ifthen}
  \newboolean{OptA}
  \newboolean{OptB}

  \setboolean{OptA}{true}
        
  \ifOptA
    \newcommand\which{Chose A} 
  \else
    \ifOptB
        \newcommand\which{Chose B}
  \else
    \newcommand\which{Chose other}
  \fi
     
  \begin{document}
  \which
  \end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand\which}`  will give an error on `}`

Comment: you are also missing a closing `\fi`

Comment: the setting of optA has no effect on anything as you never test its value after it is set.

Comment: Sorry for the original typo. And in abstracting from my actual code to this simplfied example, I forgot that the `\setboolean` does indeed come before the entire `\if...` My actual error, then, was forgetting the second `\fi`. I've edited my MWE so it leaves only the missing 2nd `\fi`.

Comment: After the edit you changed the warning to an error `! Incomplete \iftrue; all text was ignored after line 11.` and it makes no pdf output at all, you do not get `Chose other`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document produces the warning

```
(\end occurred when \iffalse on line 7 was incomplete)
```

as the outer `\ifOpA` is never closed.

Also

```
\newcommand\which}
```

would generate an error if executed due to the spurious `}`

Fixing both of those produces

```
\documentclass{article}
  
  \usepackage{ifthen}
  \newboolean{OptA}
  \newboolean{OptB}
  
  \ifOptA
    \newcommand\which{Chose A} 
  \else
    \ifOptB
        \newcommand\which{Chose B}
    \else
        \newcommand\which{Chose other}
    \fi
  \fi
  
  \setboolean{OptA}{true}
  
  \begin{document}
  \which
  \end{document}
```

[image]

The setting of `optA` obviously has no effect if you set it after the test, so moving the setting earlier:

```
 \documentclass{article}
  
  \usepackage{ifthen}
  \newboolean{OptA}
  \newboolean{OptB}
  
  \setboolean{OptA}{true}

  \ifOptA
    \newcommand\which{Chose A} 
  \else
    \ifOptB
        \newcommand\which{Chose B}
    \else
        \newcommand\which{Chose other}
    \fi
  \fi
  
 
  
  \begin{document}
  \which
  \end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Please see my comment to the OP and my edit in the question so as to show my intended code.

Comment: @murray OK but this answer still covers it I think, just adding the `\fi` the other things removing the `}` and moving the setting you did in the edit.

Comment: Yes, thank you!